# Linked List need help cant print my data. want to make an add func. in C - C++

Tags: c++, c

this is my code. i wanted to print all my list datas. but i cant cause when i write `while(llist->next != NULL)` `llist->next` is `NULL` but i don't know why. please help me :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct rame
{
    int data;   
    struct rame *next;  
};
int main()
{ 
    struct rame *llist;
    llist = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));
    llist->data = 10;
    llist->next = llist; 
    llist->next->data = 15;
    llist->next->next->data = 20;
    llist->next->next->next->data = 25; 
    llist->next->next->next->next = NULL;
    printf("test\n");
    if(llist->next == NULL)
    printf("%d\n",llist->data);
    else
    while(llist->next != NULL)
    {
         printf("%d\n",llist->data);          
         llist = llist->next;
    } 
 system("pause");
 return 0;   
}
```

hey i did everithing but my LOOP doesnt print the last data. help me :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct rame
{
    int data;   
    struct rame *next;  
};
int main()
{ 
    struct rame *llist;
    llist = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));
    llist->data = 10;
    llist->next = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));
    llist->next->data = 15;
    llist->next->next = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));
    llist->next->next->data = 20;
    llist->next->next->next = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));
    llist->next->next->next->data = 25; 
    llist->next->next->next->next = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));
    llist->next->next->next->next =  NULL;
    printf("test\n");
    while(llist->next != NULL)
    {
         printf("%d\n",llist->data);          
         llist = llist->next;
    } 
 system("pause");
 return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code

```
llist = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));
llist->data = 10;
```

allocates one memory location to `llist` , and the data of this location is assigned `10`
Next you do:

```
llist->next = llist; 
llist->next->data = 15;
```

The first line assigns the `next` link of the `llist` to itself, which makes the below state of the list

```
+--------+-----+------+
| llist  |  10 | next |-----+
+--------+-----+------+     |
    ^                       |
    |                       |
    +-----------------------v
```

Now executing `llist->next` points to `llist` itself and thus `llist->next->data` simply addresses to the `list->data` so the value 10 is changed.

In the other linking you have done, how many number of times `->next->next->....->next` you use does not matter as it will point to the same location.

To test the thing print the address of `llist` and the address of `llist->next`. You have address of `llist` and `llist->next` identical. This means `llist->data` , and `llist->next->data` are the same. and any number of indirection through `next` field is the same. So after the final assignment the `llist->data` is 25, other values previously assigned is overwritten by this.

At the last step you do: 
`llist->next->next->next->next = NULL;`

This actually makes the above diagram to:

```
+--------+-----+------+
| llist  |  10 | next |----->NULL
+--------+-----+------+
```

This results in `if(llist->next == NULL)` condition to be true and thus only the first node's contents in printed, which is the last value you have inserted = `25`

To get the proper effect, you need to allocate a new node for each next link, like for example in the context of your code:

```
llist = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));
llist->data = 10;

llist->next = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));  // we allocate a new location which 
                                               // we point to with the initial llist
llist->next->data = 15;                            // this will now set the data to 15 of
                                               // the node which we allocated on 
                                               // the previous step
```

In this case the diagram becomes

```
+--------+-----+------+      +-----------------+----+------+
| llist  |  10 | next |----->| newly allocated | 15 | next |
+--------+-----+------+      +-----------------+----+------+
```

Now you can do linking in a chain fashion by doing `llist->next->next = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));` and `llist->next-next->data = 5486` etc.

Recommended is instead of writing a chain of `next`s you can store the address of the last node temporarily in a temporary variable say `temp` and access the data element through them, like:

```
llist = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));
temp = llist;
temp->data = 5
temp->next = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));
temp = temp->next; //now temp contains the address of the newly allocated node above
temp->data = 10;
temp->next = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));
temp = temp->next;
temp->data = 15;
.
.
```

Although actually you should link these with a loop with something like the following structure

```
list_head = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));
temp = list->head;
while (some condition)
{
  temp->next = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));
  temp = temp->next;
  //if this is the last node,we assign null to identify this that there is no more nodes after this.
  temp->next = NULL;
  temp->data = value;
}
```

You need to store the list head pointer in some variable, so that with that you can traverse the entire list by following the links. Note that if you loose that head pointer, then you will not be able to get the list.

Comment: @Mat, @exasm : thanks for that. It is the best to visualise such linked structures with a pictorial representation especially for the beginners, who have difficulty to understand and follow the links.

Comment: yes but is temp a pointer or whats it? cause when i write like that my compiler tells me that it is undeclared.

Comment: @Vato Margvelashvili: yes `temp` is just a temporary pointer, you definitely need to declare it. `temp` is used for easy traversal through the link. Else you need make a long chain of next with the head pointer. I will suggest you to go though some book or text which teaches about pointers and linked lists formally. It will help you better.

Comment: can you suggest me a book? for c or c++ i learned everithing from friend and some textes at cplusplus.com but i dont really understand pointers and linked list well. and also could you tell me how important pointers are?

Comment: oh i want to ask like what kind of pointer is temp int string or smth else? like how must i declare it string *temp?

Comment: It is difficult for me to suggest one. But i can say http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_(book) and a fast one : Programming in C by Byron Gottfried .

Comment: you are using `temp` to point a structure of type `rame` so `temp` should be of type `rame *`. I recommend to go through a book instead of question-answer, which will be the correct utilization of your effort. Once you go through the books, all these answers will become clear to you.

Comment: ok no more questions :) i take you advice. thanks for helping.

Comment: @Vato Margvelashvili: happy to help. Go through a boo/text and is still there are problems, let us know.

Comment: i really like you idea with temp but, i think thats also bad because i cant use it in loop.

Comment: @Vato Margvelashvili: what do you exactly mean by you cannot use it in loop? Its standard practice.

Answer (score 6):

```
llist->next = llist;
```

`llist`'s next element is `llist` itself. You don't have a linked list per se, just a single element that loops back to itself. So:

```
llist->next->data = 15;
llist->next->next->data = 20;
llist->next->next->next->data = 25;
```

All these modify `llist->data`. And:

```
llist->next->next->next->next = NULL;
```

Sets `llist->next` to `NULL`.

You'll need to create new list elements (with `malloc`) and link them if you want to build a list. For example:

```
llist = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));
llist->data = 10;
llist->next = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));
llist->next->data = 15;
llist->next->next = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));
llist->next->next->data = 15;
....
```

Your loop is not correct: you will always skip the last entry as it's `->next` will be null, and so the loop body will not run.

Try with:

```
struct rame *cursor = llist;

while (cursor != NULL) {
  printf("%d\n", cursor->data);          
  cursor = cursor->next;
}
```

You use a second pointer to the list so that `llist` is kept unchanged and pointing at the list header. (If you don't do that, you'll never be able to get back to it since it's singly  linked.)

Comment: hmm thx. but i dont know like how to create new list elements with malloc. can you help me. thank you :)

Comment: edited my answer, but you already knew how to do it - that's how you allocated the first item :-)

Comment: hey i did everithing but i think smth is wrong with my loop cause it doesnt print 25 my last data.

Comment: @Vato Margvelashvili: did you try what I posted?

Answer (score 1):

```
llist->next->next->next->next = NULL;
```

You set the Pointer to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
llist->next->next->next->next = NULL;
```

is making `llist->next = NULL` because of `llist->next = llist;` 
You need to allocated memory for each node.for a list of two nodes:

```
llist = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));
llist->data = 10;

struct rame *llist2;
llist2 = (rame*)malloc(sizeof(struct rame));

llist2->data =15;
llist2->next = NULL;

llist->next = llist2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Draw yourself a sketch containing all allocated memory / struct(s) and the pointers. Then you will see that the snake bites in its tail at first and then its `next` is assigned NULL.